# Find the equation of the tangent to $y=x^3-2x^2+1$ in the form $y = mx+c$.

Tags: derivatives

For $P = (1, 0)$

First I would differentiate,

> $$y=x^3-2x^2+1$$

To get

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}= 3x^2-4x$$

Then add in 1 for x.

> = $-1$

But then I am really not sure where i should do with this to get the answer

> $$Y=1-x$$

How to I reach this point?

Comment: When you plugged in 1 into dy/dx you shouldn't get 16.

Comment: Yes sorry that was from a wrong example. Question still stands though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the point $(x_1, y_1) =(1,0)$ and the slope $m = -1$.

You can use the so-called "point slope formula": $$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
$$y - 0 = -1(x-1)$$

And simplify.

Comment: Thank you that rung the bell i was looking for !!

Comment: Might I suggest that you go back to basics: ask yourself "what am I supposed to find?" (Ok, I need to find the equation of a line...) "What information do I need to write an equation of a line?" (Ah yes... a *point and the slope*)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 16 is not the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=1$.